# How to find points of intersection of circles drawn a larger circle

Tags: geometry, circles

First off, sorry for the clumsy title.  I have no idea what this problem should be called.  Long story short, I'm working on some software that simulates satellites that visually monitor space junk in orbit, and I need to calculate the maximum distance from one circular orbit to another that can be completely covered by the satellites' cameras if I have *n* satellites equally spaced with and an effective range *d* that always results in an overlap.

To simplify, if I have two small, overlapping circles drawn with their center points on a larger circle as shown [in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFkSA.png), how can I find the distance from the center of the larger circle to the points of intersection of the satellites' effective areas as shown by the red circles [in this diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvsFV.png).  I'm trying to find the two circles shown in red that pass through points *E* and *F*.  Also, what are some good search terms for this kind of problem?  I will eventually need to do more complex (realistic) versions of this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $G$ be the midpoint of both $\overline{CD}$ and $\overline{EF}$, and define $r = AD$ and $\theta = m\angle DAG = \pi/n$.  Then $AG = r \cos \theta$ and $DG = r\sin \theta$.  The side lengths of the right triangle $\triangle DGE$ satisfy $DG^2 + EG^2 = DE^2$, so $EG^2 = d^2 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta$.  Therefore
\begin{equation}
AE = r \cos \theta - \sqrt{d^2 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta}, \quad \text{and} \quad
AF = r \cos \theta + \sqrt{d^2 - r^2 \sin^2 \theta}.
\end{equation}

Comment: Awesome!  I'll have to test this out tonight!  Does this process or type of problem have a name that I can search for to learn more about it?

Comment: I don't know what search terms to use.  You already put "geometry" and "circle" as keywords.  That's about all I can think of.